# React MobX - decorators + useObserver don't re-render

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I can't make React re-render with MobX.
I'm setting up everything as per the documentation. My class contains `action` and `observable` decorators. I tried hooking up the React component with `useObserver hook` or `observer HOC` and it simply **won't re-render**.

Snippet:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { action, observable } from "mobx";
import { observer, useObserver } from "mobx-react-lite";

class Timer {
  @observable secondsPassed: number = 0;

  @action increaseTimer() {
    console.log("here");
    this.secondsPassed += 1;
  }
}

const myTimer = new Timer();

setInterval(() => {
  myTimer.increaseTimer();
}, 1000);

const TimerView = ({ timer }: { timer: Timer }) => {
  return useObserver(() => <div>{timer.secondsPassed}</div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<TimerView timer={myTimer} />, document.body);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/minimal-observer-forked-gif4q?file=/src/index.tsx

I'm trying to make it work with decorators, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mobx-react observer don't fires when I set observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361090/mobx-react-observer-dont-fires-when-i-set-observable)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I had the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 4 hours of research.
My team's project was using **MobX version 4.x** and the codebase used decorators as the example above.

**BUT**

> MobX before version 6 encouraged the use of ES.next decorators to mark
> things as observable, computed and action. However, decorators are
> currently not an ES standard, and the process of standardization is
> taking a long time. It also looks like the standard will be different
> from the way decorators were implemented previously. In the interest
> of compatibility we have chosen to move away from them in MobX 6, and
> recommend the use of makeObservable / makeAutoObservable instead.

[MobX Documentation](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html)

Which means, MobX now requires to declare the class as observable in the constructor using makeObservable(this):

```
import { makeObservable } from "mobx";

class Timer {
  @observable secondsPassed: number = 0;

  @action increaseTimer() {
    this.secondsPassed += 1;
  }

  // THIS IS IMPORTANT FROM MOBX 6.X ONWARDS
  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this);
  }
}
```

From the docs:

> MobX before version 6 did not require the makeObservable(this) call in
> the constructor, but because it makes the implementation of decorator
> simpler and more compatible, it now does. This instructs MobX to make
> the instances observable following the information in the decorators
> -- the decorators take the place of the second argument to makeObservable.

For further reading [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your app with Provider and pass the store as a prop

```
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';


ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider {myTimer}> <TimerView timer={myTimer} /> </Provider>,
  document.body
);
```