# MobX Observable Changes not updating UI/rerendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mobx, mobx-react

I have a UIStore which contains the state of a popup, if it is open or not. The "enable products" button is supposed to update the UI store to open the popup, when clicking it, the state does successfully change (checking it by printing the props), but the popup does not open. I have tried passing the open state as a prop to the `<ProductPicker/>` component, however, that did not work either.

If I set the default value to be true so the popup appears on page load, it appears, and the close buttons on the popup work properly. So when I update the state inside that component it works flawlessly, but outside of it, nothing.

I am using Next.js & MobX 6.

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

class UIStore {
  @observable productPickerActive = false;

  @action setProductPickerActive = (value) => {
    console.log('Got value ' + value)
    this.productPickerActive = value;
  }
}

export default UIStore;
```

In my parent component/page, I have injected the store and can console.log the props.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Page} from "@shopify/polaris";
import {TitleBar} from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";
import ProductPicker from "../components/molecules/ProductPicker";
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

@inject('uiStore')
@observer
class Settings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


  render () {

    return (
      <Page title={"Settings"} separator>
        <TitleBar
          title={"Settings"}
          primaryAction={{
            content: 'Enable Products',
            onAction: () => this.props.uiStore.setProductPickerActive(true)
          }}
          secondaryActions={[{content: 'Print Props', onAction: () => console.log(this.props)}]}
        />
        <ProductPicker/>
      </Page>
    );
  }

}

export default Settings;
```

The popup is also an observer

```
import {ResourcePicker} from "@shopify/app-bridge-react";
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

function ProductPicker(props) {

  const handleSelection = (resources) => {
    props.uiStore.setProductPickerActive(false)
    console.log(resources);
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ResourcePicker
        resourceType={"Product"}
        open={props.uiStore.productPickerActive}
        showVariants={false}
        onCancel={() => props.uiStore.setProductPickerActive(false)}
        onSelection={(resources) => handleSelection(resources)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default inject('uiStore')(observer(ProductPicker));
```

This is my `babel.config.json`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": false }]
  ]
}
```

Why won't my button open the popup?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mobx-react observer don't fires when I set observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361090/mobx-react-observer-dont-fires-when-i-set-observable)