# How correctly fetch data by id using React mobx lite?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

I wrote some code with MOBX! Now I have an input field and I take that value and send that string to API and fetching data! afterward, I get data from the store but it doesn't refreshing when I write new city in input! I want to add city in input and display weather data immediately!!!!

here is my code on CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-wood-p13yd?file=/src/Components/NewNoteInput.tsx

Comment: Please, do not create duplicate questions, just update your old one with the new information. I will look at it when you do

Comment: @Danila I already deleted the old one!

Comment: @Danila btw have you seen my code!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `makeObservable` call inside your store constructor:

```js
  constructor() {
    // this.weather = '';
    this.weathers = [];
    this.fetchingData = false;

    makeObservable(this);
  }
```

See this answer for more details: [mobx-react observer don't fires when I set observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361090/mobx-react-observer-dont-fires-when-i-set-observable/64368599#64368599)

Also, change API link to https: `const BASEURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org";`

Also, assigning API response to `weathers` does not make sense, because your `weathers` property is an array. You need to push object to it, like that:

```js
    runInAction(() => {
      // That way every new weather response will be added to your array
      this.weathers.push(weather);
      this.fetchingData = false;
    });
```

Comment: Means you forgot something. Post the code what you've done

Comment: I already posted that.

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-wood-p13yd?file=/src/Components/NewNoteInput.tsx

Comment: You have not changed api url to https

Comment: I did! You can sign in and see also change something!

Comment: If you did, are you sure it works the same as before?