# observable and computed not being reflected in a functional component

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I am learning mobx for react-native and not able to see changes to done to observables or computed.

Basically, I want to listen to changes to observable from the component.

My store is simple:

```
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

class ConfigStore {
  rootStore = undefined;

  @observable activeConfig = {group: 'starter', TC: false};

  constructor(rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore;
  }

  @computed get termsLoaded(){
    return this.activeConfig.TC;
  }

  @action async loadPreviousConfig() {
    const configDetails = { group: 'starter', TC: false};
    try {
      const response = await AsyncStorage.multiGet([
        'group',
        'TC'
      ]);
      configDetails.group = response[0][1] || 'starter';
      configDetails.TC = response[1][1] === undefined ? false : true;
      console.log(configDetails);// shows correct previously saved config
      this.activeConfig = configDetails;
    } catch (error) {}
  }
}

export default ConfigStore;
```

From my component, I want to load first previous configuration settings and have them reflect in my app. Basically, I want to check the value of TC ater calling loadPreviousConfig, they return false still:

```
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
const ConfigComponent = (props) => {
  const { store } = props;
  const { termsLoaded, activeConfig, loadPreviousConfig } = store.configStore;

  useEffect(() => {
    const init = async () => {
        await loadPreviousConfig();
        console.log(termsLoaded); //always false even though console from the store shows it is true.
    };
    init();
  }, []); //tried [props]

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{activeConfig.group}</Text> //never changes
    </View>
  );
};

export default inject('store')(observer(ConfigComponent));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mobx-react observer don't fires when I set observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361090/mobx-react-observer-dont-fires-when-i-set-observable)

Comment: Hi @ruth hadish. Did you find an answer? Is it MobX bug?