# React MobX View and state not updating but functions are executing

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Feeling completely dumbfounded here. I've used MobX before and set it up with projects in the past.

My setup is `create-react-app` with the `experimentalDecorators` flag set to `true`. The view and state are pretty simple:

Register.tsx:

```
@observer
export class RegisterPage extends React.Component<{}, RegisterState> {
  state = new RegisterState();

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="email" value={this.state.email} placeholder="name@address.com"
               onChange={e => this.state.setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
        <input type="password" value={this.state.password}
               placeholder="Enter your password" onChange={e => this.state.setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

RegisterState.ts:

```
export class RegisterState {
  @observable
  email = '';

  @observable
  password = '';

  @action
  setEmail(email: string) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  @action
  setPassword(password: string) {
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

I am not getting any warnings or error in the console.
When tracing the issue via a debugger on the browser, I see that the function `setEmail` is executed in the RegisterState, but nothing happens after that.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mobx-react observer don't fires when I set observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64361090/mobx-react-observer-dont-fires-when-i-set-observable)

Comment: You're newing upp the RegisterState in the component class, so if an observer is changed and rerender the component a new instance of the state will be created and password and email stays at their default value?

Comment: @MartinZ the default value of the component on initial render will be `value` (coming from the state)